# React Tutorial - Page Refreshing after Comments Added

Tags: ajax, reactjs

I'm working through the official React tutorial and having a little trouble. When I add a comment I expect the comment to appear in the view, and for a split second it does, but then the page refreshes and the comment's gone.

On a related matter (and really just a request for a little FYI as I'm still learning AJAX), the code is supposed to add the comment to the JSON. I'm presuming that this wouldn't work on the Plunker but is there enough code there to actually update a JSON if the page is live?

Thanks for any help! Plunker link and code follows:

https://plnkr.co/edit/p76jB1W4Pizo0rDFYIwq?p=preview

```
    <script type="text/babel">
  // To get started with this tutorial running your own code, simply remove
  // the script tag loading scripts/example.js and start writing code here.
  var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: this.props.url,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
          this.setState({data: data});
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
          console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
      });
    },
    handleCommentSubmit: function(comment) {
      var comments = this.state.data;
      // Optimistically set an id on the new comment. It will be replaced by an
      // id generated by the server. In a production application you would likely
      // not use Date.now() for this and would have a more robust system in place.
      comment.id = Date.now();
      var newComments = comments.concat([comment]);
      this.setState({data: newComments});
      $.ajax({
        url: this.props.url,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: comment,
        success: function(data) {
          this.setState({data: data});
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
          this.setState({data: comments});
          console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
      });
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {data: []};
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
      this.loadCommentsFromServer();
      setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
    },
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div className="commentBox">
          <h1>Comments</h1>
          <CommentList data={this.state.data} />
          <CommentForm onCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  });

  var CommentList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(comment) {
        return (
          <Comment author={comment.author} key={comment.id}>
            {comment.text}
          </Comment>
        );
      });
      return (
        <div className="commentList">
          {commentNodes}
        </div>
      );
    }
  });

  var CommentForm = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {author: '', text: ''};
    },
    handleAuthorChange: function(e) {
      this.setState({author: e.target.value});
    },
    handleTextChange: function(e) {
      this.setState({text: e.target.value});
    },
    handleSubmit: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var author = this.state.author.trim();
      var text = this.state.text.trim();
      if (!text || !author) {
        return;
      }
      this.props.onCommentSubmit({author: author, text: text});
      this.setState({author: '', text: ''});
    },
    render: function() {
      return (
        <form className="commentForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Your name"
            value={this.state.author}
            onChange={this.handleAuthorChange}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Say something..."
            value={this.state.text}
            onChange={this.handleTextChange}
          />
          <input type="submit" value="Post" />
        </form>
      );
    }
  });

  var Comment = React.createClass({
    rawMarkup: function() {
      var md = new Remarkable();
      var rawMarkup = md.render(this.props.children.toString());
      return { __html: rawMarkup };
    },

    render: function() {
      return (
        <div className="comment">
          <h2 className="commentAuthor">
            {this.props.author}
          </h2>
          <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.rawMarkup()} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  });

  ReactDOM.render(
    <CommentBox url="comments.json" pollInterval={2000} />,
    document.getElementById('content')
  );

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, your problem is that the information in the json file is static (see last paragraph), so every time the comments are refreshed, you lose the new one. The way you could handle it is using the json file during the first load and then just prevent refreshing them, just adding the new ones to the comment box state (after all this is just a example and you just want to see some eye candy, don't you?).

Checking the browser's console you can see that your AJAX request to store the new file is failing, you cannot update it on Plunker, that file is immutable.